# How can you read out values of mp3 files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mp3, decode

Music is just a modulation of a sine wave, therefore it must have a "y"-value at any given time. In mp3 files, the standard sampling frequency is 44100Hz and therefore has a "y"-value once every 44100th of a second. But how can You read these values out? Preferably in Python3.

Comment: Which "values" do you mean?

Comment: Have you tried ffmpeg, it is not python, but it seems that all the python things that work with audio just shell out to ffmpeg

Answer (score 0):

Thought this won't read mp3 directly from Python, I'd suggest first converting mp3 to wav, and then reading wav from Python.

Install mpg123 if you don't have it:

```
sudo apt-get install mpg123
```

Then convert the file like this:

```
mpg123 -w file_out.wav file_in.mp3
```

Or use ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i file_in.mp3 file_out.wav
```

Then, try [scipy.io.wavfile.read](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.read.html) to read the wav file.